# Assigning a variable from a twice joined table

Tags: php, sql, join

I'm trying to assign the $row[] value to a variable so that I can use it in a form.  Since I joined the table twice, 2 columns have the same name.  I've tried to use the aliases as shown to assign the variable but they return null (maybe syntax error?).  The query checks out fine

```
<?php
//This will list player info so the user can get the correct player  ID
$STH = $db->query('
                SELECT wW.id, wW.dateStart, wW.dateEnd, wW.weekNumber, wW.team1Id, wW.team2Id, wT1.name, wT2.name 
                FROM wdlWeeks wW
                JOIN wdlTeams wT1 on wT1.id = wW.team1Id
                JOIN wdlTeams wT2 on wT2.id = wW.team2Id
            ');

//Setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Output all players with their ID's

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {

    $id = $row['wW.id'];
    $team1Name = $row['wT1.name'];
    $team2Name = $row['wT2.name'];
    $dateStart = $row['wW.dateStart'];
    $dateEnd = $row['wW.dateEnd'];
    $weekNumber = $row['wW.weekNumber'];

    echo "<option value='$id'>$team1Name vs. $team2Name (Week: $weekNumber - $dateStart - $dateEnd)</option>";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias is the column name by default, so you have two columns using 'name', and doesn't include the table alias at all. Use `AS wT1name` for example in your query, and then use those strings for the aliases pulled from $row. Like so:

```
<?php
//This will list player info so the user can get the correct player  ID
$STH = $db->query('
                SELECT wW.id, wW.dateStart, wW.dateEnd, wW.weekNumber, wW.team1Id, wW.team2Id, wT1.name AS wT1name, wT2.name AS wT2name
                FROM wdlWeeks wW
                JOIN wdlTeams wT1 on wT1.id = wW.team1Id
                JOIN wdlTeams wT2 on wT2.id = wW.team2Id
            ');

//Setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Output all players with their ID's

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $team1Name = $row['wT1name'];
    $team2Name = $row['wT2name'];
    $dateStart = $row['dateStart'];
    $dateEnd = $row['dateEnd'];
    $weekNumber = $row['weekNumber'];

    echo "<option value='$id'>$team1Name vs. $team2Name (Week: $weekNumber - $dateStart - $dateEnd)</option>";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `wW.` etc at the front of each variable the columns will be returned as just their names

Also because you have 2 columns with the same name you will have to modify your query to give one of the `name` columns another name like this

```
$STH = $db->query('
            SELECT wW.id, wW.dateStart, wW.dateEnd, wW.weekNumber, 
                 wW.team1Id, wW.team2Id, wT1.name, wT2.name as t2name
            FROM wdlWeeks wW
            JOIN wdlTeams wT1 on wT1.id = wW.team1Id
            JOIN wdlTeams wT2 on wT2.id = wW.team2Id
        ');
//Setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Output all players with their ID's

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $team1Name = $row['name'];
    $team2Name = $row['t2name'];
    $dateStart = $row['dateStart'];
    $dateEnd = $row['dateEnd'];
    $weekNumber = $row['weekNumber'];

    echo "<option value='$id'>$team1Name vs. $team2Name (Week: $weekNumber - $dateStart - $dateEnd)</option>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias per field:

SELECT wW.id, wW.dateStart, wW.dateEnd, wW.weekNumber, wW.team1Id, wW.team2Id, **wT1.name AS Team1Name, wT2.name AS Team2Name** 
                FROM wdlWeeks wW
                JOIN wdlTeams wT1 on wT1.id = wW.team1Id
                JOIN wdlTeams wT2 on wT2.id = wW.team2Id

And then:

$team1Name = $row['Team1Name']